# Excel waits a long time to start saving the document

Tags: excel, vba

When opening my sheet, I create a backup file of the current workbook almost without any delay.

When I close the file, another copy of the workbook is created also almost without any delay.

When saving the master file, Excel waits a long time (sometimes it takes several minutes) before saving.

The master file is not large, only 1.05Mb. I tried speedup solutions available on the net. Even tried reinstalling Excel.

This is the coding.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ... ' perform some actions like setting NewName and ext
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (NewName & " (backup)." & ext)
  ....
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
  ... ' perform some actions like setting NewName and ext
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (NewName & " (backup)." & ext)
  ....
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  If SaveAsUI Then Cancel = True 'Excel will close and handle saving itself.
  If ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then Cancel = True ' Cancel saving when no changes were made
  ...
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False  ' Make sure no close message pops up from the application
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
  .... ' Processing stuff amongst with resetting ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents and Calculation 
  Cancel = True ' Or it will fire twice for some reason
End Sub
```

Upon closing Excel I let it handle all the saving itself.

The workbook and copies are stored on a file server via a 1Gb network. The network isn't the problem, since the copies are saved very quickly. It is the master file that is saved sluggishly. It seems to be even slower when I work longer with the workbook.

I recently switched from Office 2007 to Office 2016 (=365). Before the switch there were no problems.

Comment: I have a feeling that Excel 365 is insanely slow on VBA. We also recently got office 365 at work and some VBA codes that used to take a minute to do would take an hour with the same code. I have localized it to some extent to be application.calculation, it that is set to automatic then it will be slow have it manual and switch to automatic when the code ends.

Answer (score 0):

The Workbook_BeforeSave event runs every time the current workbook is saved. When it completes, the workbook is saved unless Cancel has been set to True (at any point in the subroutine). Setting Cancel = True stops the workbook from being saved when the subroutine finishes.

The problem is when you call the Save method *within* the Workbook_BeforeSave event, it immediately triggers the same event again, which then tries to save the workbook again and then triggers the event again. This is repeated until you reach the limit of the number of the nested sub-routines that can run simultaneously.

SaveCopyAs saves a copy of the workbook, which doesn't trigger the BeforeSave Event, so it just saves a copy of the workbook once quickly.

Maybe 2007 didn't allow this recursive calling of the Workbook_BeforeSave event or it had a smaller limit of number of nested sub-routines.

Setting Cancel to True doesn't stop the event in its tracks, it just stops Excel from saving the workbook again after the subroutine has finished. If your intention is to not manually handle the saving when there have been no changes (detected by SaveAsUI = True), then perhaps you should just exit the sub at that point:

```
If SaveAsUI Then Exit Sub
```

The subroutine will then stop without calling the save method, but the workbook will still be saved when the sub finishes, ending the recursive loop.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, And as a result I saw that my examples were not complete, so I've corrected it. I already had EventsEnabled set to False to prevent endless looping, but it didn't show in my coding. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah that makes quite a difference. Have you been able to identify exactly where the long pause is when stepping through the code?

Comment: Yes. It actually holds on the save command. It is as if excel is not being able to detect that the server is responding or something like that.It doesn't show in the coding examples, but I actually have a message box displaying right after the save command.

On the Cancel = True... It actually works perfectly without Exit Sub. I've tried it with a messagbox showing directly after If SaveUI Then Cancel = True. It never shows when I close Excel.

Comment: And if you disable all events and save the file manually after making changes, it saves quickly?

Comment: Was just trying it. Makes no difference. The copies save quicker than the master file itself. Even if I let Excel do all the work itself. That's why I can't figure it out. Even when I just open and close the workbook, the copies save much quicker than the master file.

Comment: I mean if you comment out all of your event code entirely. So absolutely no code runs whatsoever, and you're just saving your file manually with no macros running at all.

Comment: I did. I Renamed the sub so it didn't fire anymore. Result is the same. I close excel and the copy is saved quicker than the master file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186158/discussion-between-c-van-dorsten-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether the file has already been saved before firing the save event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then Cancel = True 'Excel will close and handle saving itself.

    If ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        'Debug.Print "Fired"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried as suggested, but to no avail. Besides, this is not the issue. When the file is saved, it takes a very long time to complete, regardless of whether or not it must be saved.

Comment: Btw, I changed my example coding to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing I come to this conclusion: the difference between saving a copy or the master file is that when the master file is saved, also temporary files and cash(?) is processed. This leads to extra delay before saving a file. This is the only reason I can find that explains the difference in behaviour between saving a copy or a master file.